# Highlight table of content based on user scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a content and sidebar same as below link, bootstrap component website.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-headers

In my content I have h2 as main category and h3 as sub category.

I am wondering while user scrolling how to detect the element on the visible section to apply the active style on the related sidebar entry?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760022/what-is-the-minimum-code-to-make-scrollspy-bootstrap-sidebar-like-the-example

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi thank you. That is what I'm looking for and couldn't find it